# Streaming from opencv over sockets to multiple users

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, sockets

I am trying to send a video stream from my a usb cam to other devices on the same network using opencv python and sockets and that should be done by running a server script that sends out the stream for any number of clients connecting to it, however the problem is clear when i am trying to accept multiple clients and opencv can only get me to connect to a single client at a time,

```py
while True:
    clientSocket, clientAddr = serverSocket.accept()
    print("got connection from ", clientAddr)
    if clientSocket:

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        codedFrame = pickle.dumps(frame)
        msg = struct.pack("Q", len(codedFrame)) + codedFrame
        try:
            clientSocket.sendall(msg)
        except Exception:
            print("Connection lost, exiting stream")
            cap.release()
            clientSocket.close()
        print("started stream")
```

How can i have the ability to send the stream to multiple connections without them cutting off the stream from each other.

this should be a simple script but for the life of me i couldn't find anything similar without using complicated systems with gstreamer or webservers which defy the purpose of it being a simple script

the server is a very old raspberry pi 3b and is running a custom version of raspbian which makes setting up anything other than a simple python env a nightmare and this is why a simple script is the best way to go about it

Comment: How about **publishing** your frames to a broker like **Redis** and allowing clients to **subscribe** if they want them? Pub/sub architecture.

Comment: this would have been a clean solution but the intended server here is a pi 3b and it is running a custom version of raspbian which makes setting up stuff a nightmare so a small simple script is a must @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by using udp streams instead of tcp and that makes it a hell of a lot easier to send data without requiring a connection.

if you face the same problem or aspire to acheive the same goal then check out the code to my solution here https://github.com/RobEn-AAST/ROV-camsys